# Pgadmin4 1.6 Restore Server Failed

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

Before trying to upgrade to v2+ I backed up my Ubuntu server 16.04 with Pgadmin's feature for backing up the server, not the db.  The upgrade to 2.0 and another to 2.1 failed, spent a day trying to unfail it, so I  installed Pgadmin 1.6 on a new clean Ubuntu box with Postgres 9.5 running.  This is for dev and using Vagrant so easy to spin up a new box.

So far no matter how I configure the restore options it installs the whole server backup I did in the db table of the new db I had to setup to use Pgadmin's restore.  This is awkward and unusable.  I found no guidance on restoring the whole server.  The docs describe restoring the db only.

Any ideas what to do?  I'm new to databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have used `pg_dumpall` utility to create backup of complete server then you can simple run the

```
psql -f <your_backup_file> postgres
```

Ref: [Link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-ALL)

Comment: Thanks!  The restore went well.  Nice to learn something new also. Points to you :-)